APIMS CORS Policy for Subdomains Wildcard
When trying to add the CORS policy in my APIMS, with subdomain wildcard origin like the following :
<origin>https://*.example.com</origin>
and im getting this error:
Error in element 'cors' on line , column 10: Origin must be a valid URL consisting of scheme, host, and port only
Even though this works completely fine when I add the same policy directly in the App Service CORS configuration.
Tried to override previous policies but still dont work.
